# Why aren't mandatory options requested in the signature of ASP.NET Core "AddXXX" methods?

Tags: api-design, interfaces, asp.net-core, parameters

I've developing a .NET Core library meant to simplify the configuration of the authentication within our SSO system. It will expose two methods to be called in the `Program.cs` (or `Startup.cs`) of ASP.NET Core web apps:

- `public static AuthenticationBuilder AddFederatedAuthentication (this IServiceCollection services)`
- `public static IApplicationBuilder UseFederatedAuthentication (this IApplicationBuilder app)`

I was taking inspiration of similar packages, like [AddGoogle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.googleextensions.addgoogle) and I found something that seems weird from a API design point of view: The connection with Google **requires** a client id and a client secret. Those options can be configured in an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.googleextensions.addgoogle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-googleextensions-addgoogle(microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationbuilder-system-action((microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-google-googleoptions)))) of the `AddGoogle` method, but they are not enforced in the method signature, so it's easy to simply do `services.AddGoogle()` and have a misconfigured app.

The same design is followed in similar libraries, like [AddFacebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.facebookauthenticationoptionsextensions.addfacebook).

Wouldn't it be better to add required options as parameters to the method signature, to guide the usage of these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share your frustrations with this design pattern. I guess the reasoning is that it makes everything "easy" for a default setup.

I think what happens is the developers take a section of their DI/Framework setup

```
services.AddTransient(x);
var endpoint = configuration.GetSection(y)
services.AddSingleton(new myThing());
```

and just copy it into an extension method. What's worse is they will often make the lower level setup constructors `internal` so you cant even call them yourself if you need to do a more complex setup, or use a different DI framework etc.

Would a more complex builder pattern, or overloads on the "simple" method be the best approach? Its arguable.

What *should* be supported though is the ability to make derived classes, call constructors and use these classes in normal OOP ways rather than locking them down to a single approved usage.

Then if you don't like the provided helper classes, you are free to make your own.

Comment: The problem with making classes extensible is that they can be extended in ways that the original author did not anticipate, and then those ways often have to be supported.  "Classic OOP" supports the notion that classes (from a framework, library or API) should only be interacted with through their public interface; deriving from another class assumes knowledge of and access to the base class's internal members.

Comment: This is why folks like Eric Lippert often advocate for `sealed` classes as a default.  Classes should only be "unsealed" when they are specifically designed to be inherited from.

Comment: Sure, it makes things easier for the library developer, but the library is less functional and the classes 'closed for extension'. Remember in the extremes of this case we are talking about tying your libraries to a specific DI framework and Config file reader

Comment: @Ewan You're not wrong about "closed for extension", but Robert's point is more that no one ever asked if it was _intended_ to be extended this way (because classes are by default extensible, it's usually not an explicitly made decision). Inheritance can open the door too much, whereas composition ensures that the library's original class can still only be used the way it was intended to be. A derived class is more liable to break things or shoot itself in the foot, it might need more concrete knowledge of the base class' implementation, etc.

Comment: its a fair argument, but an academic one. In practice Its a basic ask to be able to instantiate an object without being forced to use DI, or to pass in a connection string to a constructor rather than have it read from config. It's expected that libraries have a degree of customisation options available, such as exposing event handers or being able to pass in alternate implementations of dependencies, Its expected that they should implement a mockable interface for tests. This pattern often prevents these things